# How to insert multiple rows with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am trying to insert multiple rows in SQLite using ionic framework. Single row  insert in working fine.

even if i run

```
 INSERT INTO categories (category_id, category_name,category_type) VALUES (1,"test",1),(2,"test again", 2);
```

this is also working fine.
but when i try to create a dynamic string it gives me error "could not prepare statement (1 near "?": syntax error)".

```
.success((function (result) {
                 var query = "INSERT INTO categories (category_id, category_name,category_type) VALUES ?";
                 var data = [];
                 result.forEach(function (category) {
                         data.push([category.id, category.category_name, category.category_type]);
                     });
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[data]).then(function (res) {
         console.log("inserted");
     }, function (err) {
   console.dir(err);
    });
```

Comment: You add one ? even though you say there will be three columns inserted. This will not work.

Comment: i am  passing data  as a array

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add multiple parameters to your insert, just like you do in your test query (the first you mentioned), then pass all arguments as a one dimensional array:

```
.success((function (result) {
                 var query = "INSERT INTO categories (category_id, category_name,category_type) VALUES ";
                 var data = [];
                 var rowArgs = [];
                 result.forEach(function (category) {
                         rowArgs.push("(?, ?, ?)");
                         data.push(category.id);
                         data.push(category.category_name);
                         data.push(category.category_type);
                     });
                 query += rowArgs.join(", ");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[data]).then(function (res) {
         console.log("inserted");
     }, function (err) {
   console.dir(err);
    });
```

This code will produce query like:

```
INSERT INTO categories (category_id, category_name,category_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?);
```

and your data array will be of size 12, where every 3 entries in array will be one row of data to be inserted.

Those numbers are just example and they depend on the size of `result`.

Comment: getting this error 
number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count

Comment: my loop is executing 40 times

Comment: `console.log(data.length);` and `console.log(query);` - see if everything looks okay

Comment: length is 184, and query is 

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO categories (category_id, user_id, category_name,category_type) VALUES

Comment: (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?), (?, ?, ?,?)

Comment: You didn't have to paste it here. Just count number of '?' in the query and see if it's equal to 184. Tip: use `console.log((query.match(new RegExp("\\?", "g")) || []).length);`

Answer (score 5):

**This seems to be an approach:**

```
var query = "INSERT INTO categories (category_id,category_name,category_type) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

...

```
.success((function (result) {

$cordovaSQLite.transaction(function(tx){

   result.forEach(function (category) {
      tx.executeSql(query, [category.id, category.category_name, category.category_type]);
   });
}).success(function(){

  .....
});
```

**I have also seen this approach:**

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION");
result.forEach(function (category) {
    $cordovaSQLite.executeSql(query, [category.id, category.category_name, category.category_type]);
       });
$cordovaSQLite.execute("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
```

Comment: i guess this approach doesnot seems good. if i have 10000 loops  and it will insert each row 10000 times in db. i want to insert all records in once. +1 for second approach

Comment: @HituBansal. what happened in second approach?

Comment: @HituBansal, when you say insert 1000 times, do you mean it does a round trip from client to server 1000 times, or that it makes 1 round trip, and then writes the row 1000 distinct times on that one round trip?

Comment: it will round 1 trip and i will get 1000 rows. I am talking on Client side.
According to your code  . $cordovaSQLite.executeSql, tx.executeSql will execute 1000 times.  which is inserting the rows into database.  i am very  close to Googie answer.

Comment: @HituBansal, if it makes 1 roundtrip and inserts 1000 times, that's exactly how it's supposed to work. The round trips are what cost a lot. You still have to make 1000 inserts for 1000 rows. That will never change.

Comment: See Googie answer. i guess that make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use arrays as parameter values.

You have to create an SQL command string with three parameters for the three columns, and execute it multiple times.

To ensure efficiency, you have to do all INSERTs in a single transaction.

Comment: Executing multiple time is not optimize way.  Can't we do in single insert?

Comment: AFAIK none of those JavaScript frameworks support prepared statements.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich: i am also disagree with CL for the same

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I was not talking about transactions (and as far as transactions are concerned, I agree with you), but about whether `execute()` can handle arbitrary numbers of rows. JavaScript does not have Python's equivalent of `executemany()`.

Comment: @CL., so your argument is not that OP cannot achieve what he wants but not in the way he's going about it?

Comment: Well, he *can* almost achieve what he asked for with Googie's answer.But this appears to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I see what you mean. OP asked for X and in order to stick with thread, your response was X is wrong. To say not X but Y would confuse the purpose of the thread?

Comment: Yes, but you also have to find out what Y actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2, angular 2 and typescript

```
import {Platform, NavController, NavParams, Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular'`;

//SqlStorage uses SQLite or WebSQL (development only!) to store data in a
// persistent SQL store on the filesystem.
//automatically

public  getDB() {

        // if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        // } else {
        this.db = new Storage(SqlStorage, {name: this.db_name});
        this.db = this.db._strategy._db;
        // }
        return this.db;
    }



query(sql:any, params:any = []) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                try {

                    console.log('query try');

                    this.getDB().transaction((transaction) => {

                        transaction.executeSql(sql, params, (transaction, success) => {
                            // resolve(this.fetchAll(success));
                            resolve(success);

                        }, (transaction, error) => {

                            reject(error);

                        });

                    });


                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Unable to open database,", +error);
                    reject(error);
                }

            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Googie

Thanks for the solution.
But I had problems with inserting the data and it came out that this line:

`$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[data])...`

was the problem. And the solution was to write the data without brackets like this:

`$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, data)...`

because `data` is already an array.

Thought this maybe could be helpful for others.

cheers

Answer (score -1):

In any case it's a bad practice to write a raw sql queries in the code. Is it possible to use some Node ORM with ionic-framework? For example node-orm2: https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2

In this case your solution will looks like this:

```
var data = [];
result.forEach(function (category) {
    data.push({'id' : category.id, 'name' : category.category_name, 'type' : category.category_type});
});

Category.create(data, function (err, items) {
    // err - description of the error or null
    // items - array of inserted items
});
```

Comment: Doing directly what you need to do can't be a bad practice, even if it's raw machine instructions in the code. What may become a bad practice is using high-level astraction layers like ORM, and then hacking it in order to get lower-level access.