# How to insert and get multiple data in cordovasqlite ionic?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I want to insert and get multiple json data in  SQLite ionic and I also want to sync that stored data.

```js
var query ="INSERT INTO triptable(tripReqId,tripProjectCode,tripProjectName,tripTravellerName,tripStartDate,tripEndDate,tripOriginCity,tripTrNo,tripDestiCity,tripFeedBAckProvided,tripStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

  angular.forEach(function(category){
       tripsdata.push(category.tripReqId);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripProjectCode);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripProjectName);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripTravellerName);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripStartDate);
       tripsdata.push(category.tripEndDate);
      tripsdata.push(category.tripOriginCity);
      tripsdata.push(category.tripTrNo);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripDestiCity);
       tripsdata.push(category.tripFeedBAckProvided);
        tripsdata.push(category.tripStatus);
      });
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[tripsdata]).then(function(res){
    console.log("Rows are inserted"+tripData);
    }, function (err) {
                  console.log("Rows are not Inserted");
    });
  });
```

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181226/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-a-parameter . If its not what you want let me know .

Comment: i already tried that and that was working properly..

Comment: i would like to parse json data in sqlite ionic and also want to retrieve that data